# Compiling a project for client/server [Linker error] undefined reference to

Tags: c++, sockets, compiler-errors

I am new to c++ and I am trying to connect to a server (127.0.0.1:4444). When I try to compile this code I get:

[Linker error] undefined reference to WSASartup@8

[Linker error] undefined reference to socket@12

[Linker error] undefined reference to inet_addr@4

[Linker error] undefined reference to etc...

The code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    SOCKET sock;
    SOCKADDR_IN sin;
    char buffer[255];
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &WSAData);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(4444);
    connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Where are my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See heading **2.4** at the [Winsock Programmer’s FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/newbie.html)

See the Community Additions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for instructions on how to link with  ws2_32.lib on various versions of Microsoft VC++.

You need to link with ws2_32.lib.